# Facebook Debugger and URL variables

Tags: php, facebook, debugging

Facebook Debugger thinks **http://sub.domain.com/?s=123** is the same as **http://sub.domain.com** (which is not!) thus getting completely wrong page and **og: values** - anyone know why? To me it looks it simply strips anything behind "/?"

I have checked multiple times the page in question in Firefox FIREBUG and the og: values are OK (that is: exactly as expected) yet in FB Debugger they are still wrong.

When loaded in browser og: values are as expected (for the specific article being shown) yet in FB Debugger the info is from the initial "main" page of the website (that is stripped URL variables)...

**SOLVED**

Ah, it was my mistake once again when I misspelled the variable that is producing the canonical URL for my script which is the same one that inputs it for the og:url META TAG...thanx to **@CBroe** for pointing out

Comment: Because you _told Facebook so_, by specifying `http://lego.queryen.com/` as `org:url`, duh?

Comment: @CBroe oh, got to check it

Comment: (And just FYI, that disabling of the right click makes the whole page really effing unusable ... I can’t even decide to open links in a new tab if I want to, or mark any text if I need to copy&paste it into a search engine or look up a translation …? You should really remove this, it is massive nonsense. Nothing much on that site would be worth “stealing” to begin with IMHO.)

Comment: @CBroe oh my, yes, you were right: I misspelled the variable that is inputting my canonical URL (the same var places it to og:url) - if you would post your answer as separate post I would sign it as the right one...as for the disabling of the right click: it was because of some long time ago when I was doing only FLASH websites having selectable text makes big problems for those sites

Answer (score 0):

> Facebook Debugger thinks `http://sub.domain.com/?s=123` is the same as `http://sub.domain.com` (which is not!) thus getting completely wrong page and og: values - anyone know why?

Because you specified the `og:url` meta property as `http://lego.queryen.com/`, which tells the Facebook scraper that this was the real URL for this piece of content, and that it should please go and request that one now to get the actual meta data.